# Special character in XML

Tags: xml

Our XML validation keeps falling over on a special character that appears throughout a block of text. It looks like a square with four F's inside it. (see shot below). I am using CDATA tags.

I could strip it out if I just knew what it was.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Any ideas?

Paul

Comment: What XML library? What encoding? What validation error message? What do you see when you dump the file in hex?

Comment: take a screenshot or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like you are trying to include the non-character U+FFFF in your XML file. This non-character is, of course, not allowed in XML files.

Comment: Needed to use a script to strip out high ASCII chars. Used Ben Nadel's version at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1155-Cleaning-High-Ascii-Values-For-Web-Safeness-In-ColdFusion.htm